# how can I create model associated to another by passing its id in a link [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my project show view I have a button which goes to create a new question associated to this project I am passing its id.

```
<%= link_to 'Create question', new_question_path(:project_id => @project.id) %>
```

in my questions controller I have set_project method which set that project I pass in the link:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :set_project, only: [:new, :create, :edit]
 before_action :set_categories, only: [:new, :edit]

 def new
  @question = Question.new
  @question.answers.build
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
 end

 # GET /questions/1/edit
 def edit
 end

 # POST /questions
 # POST /questions.json
 def create
  @question = Question.new(question_params)
  @question.project = @project

 end

 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
 def question_params
  params.require(:question).permit(:question, :question_type,
                                   projects_attributes: [:id, :name, :category_id])
 end

 # now we are taking all projects, later we have to take the project correspondent (only one)
 def set_project
  #@project_options = Project.all.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}
  if params[:project_id]
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end
 end

 def set_categories
  @category_options = Category.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}
 end
end
```

My view is a bit tricky because if this question is related to a new project I have to show the project name input and also user should select its category, otherwise it gonna show only the project name.

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>
  <% if @project %>
    <div class="field">
        <label>Project Name</label><br>
        <%= @project.name %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
      <%= f.fields_for :projects do |project_form| %>
          <div class="field">
            <%= project_form.label :name, 'Project Name' %><br>
            <%= project_form.text_field :name %>
          </div>
           <div class="field">
             <%= project_form.label :category_id %><br>
             <%= project_form.select :category_id, @category_options %>
           </div>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :question, rows: 3, cols:40 %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :question_type %><br>
    <%= f.select :question_type, Question::QUESTIONS_TYPES, prompt: 'Select a question type' %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

Even I can submit the question to the database but the project associated is nil. Any suggestions how to make this working will be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the **Nested Resources** section of the rails guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Essentially though, you need to add your nested resource to your `routes.rb` file:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :questions
end
```

You will then be able to link to the `new` action of the `QuestionsController` passing the appropriate `project` along to the controller:

```
link_to 'New Question', new_project_question_path(@project)
```

Then in your controller, you can locate the project and create a new question for it:

```
def new
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @question = @project.questions.new
end
```

Have a read of the rails guides - they explain most of this stuff pretty well.

Comment: Thanks Jon for the tip, yes I saw this solution in a blog tutorial. The only difference is sometimes I don't pass @project to the link if concerning a new project, in this case my form should care the project fields as well. Could the Nested resources work too for my question?